# Updating FormControl after adding required attribute dynamically using [attr.required]

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular4-forms

I have a single input defined as a **FormControl** and bound to **ngModel**.
It looks the following:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- If this input is empty the POB input should be required -->
<input type="text"
           id="addrs_house"
           name="addrs_house"
           #addrs_house="ngModel"
           required
           [ngStyle]="{hasError:addrs_house.invalid)}"
           [(ngModel)]="model.house">
 <!-- This input is dynamicaly required, dependant on the house input -->        
<input type="text"
           id="addrs_po"
           name="addrs_po"
           [(ngModel)]="model.pob"
           #addrs_po="ngModel"
           [attr.required]="model.house ? null : ''"
           [ngStyle]="{hasError:addrs_po.invalid}">
```

**TS:**

```
// In the component Im refencing the FormInput model as so
@ViewChild('addrs_po') addrs_po: ElementRef;
```

**The problem:**
The *required* attribute does get added to the **POB input** but the **ngModel of the FormControl does not get updated** accordingly with errors object.

Comment: why are you setting the attr.required null?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the property binding not the attribute binding:

```
[required]="!model.house"
```

This will properly update the required state